# Installing Spatialite on Centos7: select mod_extension() doesn't work

Tags: spatialite, sqlite, centos

I'm trying to install Spatialite on a CentOS 7 server.

Sqlite (version 3.7.17 ...), works fine.

Using the command

```
yum list | grep spatial
```

the result is the follow

[image]

So I've installed Spatialite using the command

```
sudo yum install libspatialite
```

When I try to check abot spatialite version I obtain ...

[image]

If I search for "spatial" libraries in my system I obtain ...

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pehaps you have not set "enable_load_extension" into "True" before trying to load mod_spatialite.

Comment: Where should I set it?

Comment: It depends on how you connect the SQLite db. Some examples can be found here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/93eFMPty05k. SQLite documents may also be useful https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/enable_load_extension.html. And stackoverflow may help as well because you have a generic SQLite problem that is not specific to SpatiaLite module. You may even need to recompile, see the footnote in: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#f1.

Comment: At the momenti I'm trying simply to connect from command line but it doesn't work ....

Comment: Sorry for being blind. You try to load mod_spatialite but you do not seem to have mod_spatialite.so in your system. What you need to install is maybe libsqlite3-mod-spatialite.

Comment: It seems that there is no package  `libsqlite3-mod-spatialite` for CentOS7 ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved ...

I don't have to use `mod_spatialite` but `libspatialite.so.5`...

In my system ..

```
# find /  | grep mod_spatialite
```

is empty but ...

```
# find /  | grep libspatialite
/usr/lib64/libspatialite.so.5
/usr/lib64/libspatialite.so.5.1.0
```

So, I've tried in this way ....

```
# sqlite3 test
sqlite> select load_extension('/usr/lib64/libspatialite.so.5');
sqlite> select spatialite_version();
4.1.1
```

You can set

```
# export "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64"
```

so, in more simply way ...

```
# sqlite3 test
sqlite> select load_extension('libspatialite.so.5');
sqlite> select spatialite_version();
4.1.1
sqlite> select InitSpatialMetaData();
sqlite> select distance(makepoint(151.23346, -33.91674, 4326),        makepoint(151.20435, -33.86712, 4326));
0.0575285711625093
```

So, it seems that spatialite works fine!

Comment: Good if it works for you. However it should be possible to get also the mod_spatialite.so but I do not know how. This RedHat RPM build contains them both http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/29688382/dir/redhat_el_6/com/libspatialite7-4.2.0-3.2.i686.rpm.html.

Comment: Yes on RedHat is differentm but I'm on CentOS7 ...

Comment: By https://danielmiessler.com/study/fedora_redhat_centos/ CentOS is basically RedHat without support. What is possible with RedHat should be possible with CentOS as well but you might need to compile by yourself. If you really want to know how it should be done write mail to SpatiaLite users forum. Sandro Furieri and some other specialists tends to be responsive.

Comment: Worked like a charm on centos 7. Thanks for this answer :)